# User and System Appications Folder

Tags: macos, finder

In Mavericks (OS X 10.9), the User's Application folder is a separate folder from the System Application folder. Is there a way to see these two folders as one, similar to how it works on Windows? Otherwise, having both in the Finder Sidebar looks confusing and clunky:
[image]

Comment: This must be an error. The app you are showing is just a short cut that ended in separate folder. It is actually not there, so find the original app and delete that shortcut.

Comment: You might also want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9048601

Comment: No. It's not an error. It's an alias, sure, but Racket's working fine. My questions is more along the lines of given two separate Applications folders: /Users/user/Applications and /System/Applications, how can I combine the view of these into a single folder. The answer below sounds promising, but isn't straightforward

Comment: ~/Applications/ has been there for ages

Answer (score 1):

You can create a smart folder which shows the contents of both folders. Go to File → New Smart Folder and add both the directories as rules for the smart folder.

Comment: How do you create a rule for the contents of the directory? I looked at adding the folder contents via criteria other->search for folder, which provided Document Container: Containing Folder of Item and a text box to type in the folder name, but it didn't appear to work with matches and any version of the folder name, or is, begins with, etc.

Comment: Smart Folder isn't as smart as one may think. ;-) criteria->kind = application. The caveat is that you'll get ALL applications on your mac as result. even those in your download folder or somewhere else.